# Macro to copy to another sheet in one line horizontally

Tags: excel, vba

Wondering if there is way to copy data from one excel sheet in table format and transform into a single line of data via macro for excel 2007?

For instance, I have got following data in table format;

> **Date - Name - Amount**
> 02/03/2011 - John - -20.00
> 05/03/2011 - Peter   - 30.89
> 05/03/2011 - Anthony - 988.00
> .....
> ..
> .

The macro should eventually will copy data above to another excel sheet with horizontally (transpose) one continuously with added '@' as a separator.

> 02/03/2011
> John
> -20.00
> @
> 05/03/2011
> Peter
> 30.89
> @
> 05/03/2011 
> Anthony
> 988.00
> ...
> ..
> .

can this be done?

I only could work for 1st line, how could I continue with subsequent?

```
Range("A2:F2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
```

Comment: It might be worth you recording a macro while you the above manually just once or twice. Then you will have the basis for the code and will probably only need to make a few changes.

Comment: the problem might be the number of row in the table might be growing over time.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a loop, something like

```
Dim workingrow As Range
For Each workingrow in UsedRange.Rows
  workingrow.Columns("A:F").Copy
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("whereveryouwant").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
       Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= False, Transpose:=True
Next workingrow
```